# MVC Video input time doesn't change

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, video

I have an web site. In this web site I have video element. I get video from controller as a file then make it source of video. Problem is that I can't change time of video time dynamically from bar. It doesn't go to spesific time. Example problem is in this link.

https://www.tzob.org.tr/Media/Get/?guid=74f52d4e-a863-48f2-a9d4-d98381e341c2.mp4&category=file .

I cant go to 20. second directly.

```
 public ActionResult Get(int refUser,string guid,string type="Video")
        {
            Tuple<byte[], string> data = VideoRepository.Get(refUser, guid,type);
            if (data == null)
                return null;

            return File(data.Item1, data.Item2);
        }
```

Code above is for controller that to send source of video to view.

```
 <video id="choosenVideo" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" controls preload="auto" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 80px; min-height: 400px;background-color: white;">
                        <source id='currentVID' src="" type="video/mp4">
                    </video>
```

Code above is video tag in view.

```
function chooseFromGalery(param, param2) {
    var player = document.getElementById("choosenVideo");
    var currentVid = document.getElementById("currentVID");


    var link = personalizeVideosGet + "?refUser=" + userId + "&guid=" + param;

    currentVid.setAttribute("src", link);
    player.load();


}
```

Code above is for giving source to video.

Why can't I change video time directly from bar? How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you store video  in folder in server and copy the path to src it will work

I had the same problem and it was because we send the videos as a byte arrays.